# Mysql LOG only specific users

Tags: logs, mysql

I need to set up some logging on my debian squeeze x64 mysql 5.1 Server:

1) logging when users logged in and logged off
2) logging only specific users commands

set up logging which will not slow down performance of mysql server or harddrives.

Is it possible to set logging only last month?

Is it possible to set up logging only in specific hours in a day?

I don't want gigabytes of useless logs, just logs of specific users in one file.

Answer (score 1):

You need [MySQL 5.6 EE](https://blogs.oracle.com/MySQL/entry/new_in_mysql_enterprise_edition). With CE you could [write your own audit plugin](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/writing-audit-plugins.html).
Or use the poor man auditing with [custom triggers](http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-logon-and-logoff-trigger-for-auditing) and write your own retention routine.